# Sublime - Multiple Word Replace

Tags: replace, sublimetext

I am trying to use the Sublime "Find in Files" to replace multiple words with another word in multiple files, for example:

```
Dog -> Cat
Hat -> Shoe
Farm -> City
```

In notepad++ I was able to do this using the following find and replace conditions:

```
Find: (Dog)|(Hat)|(Farm)
Replace: (?1Cat)(?2Shoe)(?3City)
```

Comment: have you ever found a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [RegReplace](http://facelessuser.github.io/RegReplace/). Here's a [simple guide](https://css-tricks.com/run-multiple-find-replace-commands-sublime-text/) that describes the steps to configure and use this package.

[image: Screenshot of RegReplace]